# Specifying template filenames for template.ParseFiles

Tags: go

My current directory structure looks like the following:

```
App
  - Template
    - foo.go
    - foo.tmpl
  - Model
    - bar.go
  - Another
    - Directory
      - baz.go
```

The file `foo.go` uses `ParseFiles` to read in the template file during `init`.

```
import "text/template"

var qTemplate *template.Template

func init() {
  qTemplate = template.Must(template.New("temp").ParseFiles("foo.tmpl"))
}

...
```

Unit tests for `foo.go` work as expected. However, I am now trying to run unit tests for `bar.go` and `baz.go` which both import `foo.go` and I get a panic on trying to open `foo.tmpl`.

```
/App/Model$ go test    
panic: open foo.tmpl: no such file or directory

/App/Another/Directory$ go test    
panic: open foo.tmpl: no such file or directory
```

I've tried specifying the template name as a relative directory ("./foo.tmpl"), a full directory ("~/go/src/github.com/App/Template/foo.tmpl"), an App relative directory ("/App/Template/foo.tmpl"), and others but nothing seems to work for both cases. The unit tests fail for either `bar.go` or `baz.go` (or both).

Where should my template file be placed and how should I call `ParseFiles` so that it can always find the template file regardless of which directory I call `go test` from?

Comment: Can you post a clear example of what you are trying to do? I tried `ParseFiles("../Template/foo.tmpl")` from `Model` and it works just fine.

Comment: But if I try to run `go test` in a deeper directory it no longer works again. From what I can figure, `go test` always sets the current working directory and then `ParseFiles` uses this as the base directory to find templates instead of it being relative to the file that calls `ParseFiles`. This is very fragile so I figure I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I've updated my question to show the problem I'm running into.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Helpful tip:

Use `os.Getwd()` and `filepath.Join()` to find the absolute path of a relative file path.

Example

```
// File: showPath.go
package main
import (
        "fmt"
        "path/filepath"
        "os"
)
func main(){
        cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
        fmt.Println( filepath.Join( cwd, "./template/index.gtpl" ) )
}
```

First off, I recommend that the `template` folder only contain templates for presentation and not go files.

Next, to make life easier, only run files from the root project directory. This will help make the path to an file consistent throughout go files nested within sub directories. Relative file paths start from where the current working directory, which is where the program was called from.

Example to show the change in current working directory

```
user@user:~/go/src/test$ go run showPath.go
/home/user/go/src/test/template/index.gtpl
user@user:~/go/src/test$ cd newFolder/
user@user:~/go/src/test/newFolder$ go run ../showPath.go 
/home/user/go/src/test/newFolder/template/index.gtpl
```

As for test files, you can run individual test files by supplying the file name.

```
go test foo/foo_test.go
```

Lastly, use a base path and the `path/filepath` package to form file paths.

Example:

```
var (
  basePath = "./public"
  templatePath = filepath.Join(basePath, "template")
  indexFile = filepath.Join(templatePath, "index.gtpl")
)
```