# Go: serve static templates

Tags: go

I can't seem to get the static templates served. Here's my code

Go Directory Structure

```
src
     /github.com
          /sam
               /hello
                   auth.go
                   main.go
                   /templates
                       signup.html
```

auth.go

```
package main
//...
func homeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, "signup", nil)
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, user *data.User) {
    t := template.Must(template.New("tele").ParseFiles("templates/" + tmpl + ".html"))
    err := t.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, user)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    //...
    http.Handle("/templates/", http.StripPrefix("/templates/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("templates"))))
    //...
}
```

signup.html

```
{{ define "signup" }}
//html code
{{ end }}
```

Ran `go install github.com/sam/auth` and opened `localhost:3000` but I still get the panic error:

```
open templates/signup.html: no such file or directory
```

WHY???

Comment: Because you don't run your program in the correct directory maybe?

Comment: uhh nope, corrected the editing mistake.

Comment: So what is your current working directory? Are you running your application from within your project's root directory? See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19035187/go-specifying-template-filenames-for-template-parsefiles)

Comment: And both questions are a result of not really understanding how paths are resolved. Relative paths are exactly that _relative_. They are relative to your current working directory. You either have to have the templates in your working directory, or you have to configure an absolute path where your program finds your templates or you can use something like [osext](http://godoc.org/bitbucket.org/kardianos/osext) and have the templates relative to your binary path.

Comment: Also why did you post the same exact question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413997/go-error-serving-templates)?

Answer (score 1):

The path you use - `templates/` - is relative to where the program is run. if you want it to work regardless of where you run the program, you should use an absolute path, like `$GOPATH/src/github.com/sam/hello/templates/`

But this is fragile too, since the directory can move, and your program will not run on another machine. I would suggest you look at bundling your assets (the templates) with the binary. A good way to do that is using [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata)